# need to update an attribute via csv in magento

Tags: magento

I have about 5,000 attribute in my magento store.I have uploaded all of them via csv.Now i want to update few attribute via csv.I am able to update the quantity attribute via this code http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/mass-update-stock-levels-in-magento-fast/.

Now I want to update one more attribute brand created by me.I found this code http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/updating-product-qty-in-magento-in-an-easier-faster-way/ i changed to fit my needs but it did not work

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this can help you: http://blog.rahuldadhich.com/catalog-product-update-magento-1-x-csv/

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to pay attention to 2 fields, SKU and the attribute(s) you'll be updating.  For this example I'm going to work with a color attribute that is a text field (the code will change slightly if you're dealing with anything other than a text field).

First, since you probably don't want to build a full module to handle the import you'll need to initialize magento in a new PHP file.  Add the full path to magento before app/Mage.php unless you are running this script in the magento root.

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();
```

Next you'll want to process your CSV file into an array.  Make sure that the first line of your CSV contains column titles.  This function should take care of processing the CSV to an array: https://gist.github.com/jaywilliams/385876

Once that script is included you can run something like this:

```
$csv_products = csv_to_array('path/to/your/csv/file.csv');
```

You can then loop through each product, lookup the SKU and update its color attribute.  This assumes that the SKU attribute is lowercase `sku` and the color attribute is lowercase `color`.

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($csv_products);$i++) {
    $currentProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$csv_products[$i]['sku']);
    if($currentProduct) {
        $currentProduct->setColor($csv_products[$i]['color']);
        $currentProduct->save();
        //with 5,000 products you probably want to output something here so
        //that you can make sure the script is running.  Just make sure that
        //you don't lose track of Product not found output (from below).
        echo 'Success '.$i. ': ' . $csv_products[$i]['sku'] ."\n";
    } else {
        //we don't want to break the loop, but you'll probably want to record
        //that this sku can't be found in magento.  You can just echo this
        //since the script will probably be running in the console.
        echo 'Product not found: '.$csv_products[$i]['sku']."\n";
    }
}
```

You will need to run this from the command line as it can take quite a while.  When I did something similar updating aprox 4,000 products it took about 2 hours (more attributes, and using dropdowns as well).

To work with a dropdown (still using the color example) you can add something like this before looping through the products:

```
$color_attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product', 'color');
$loaded_colors = array();
$valuesCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')->setAttributeFilter($color_attribute->getId())->setStoreFilter(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID, false)->load();   
foreach ($valuesCollection as $item) {
    $loaded_colors[strtolower($item->getValue())] = $item->getId();
}
```

Then you can set a color attribute like this instead:

```
$currentProduct->setColor($loaded_colors[$csv_products[$i]['color']]);
```

With multi-select you'll need to provide CSV to setColor.  Something like this would work (assuming your CSV has a comma separated list of options in the individual field).

```
$colorArray = explode(',',$csv_products[$i]['color']);
if(sizeof($colorArray) > 1) {
    for($k = 0;$k<sizeof($colorArray);$k++) {
        $colorArray[$k] = $loaded_colors[$colorArray[$k]];
    }
    $colorString = implode(',',$colorArray);
} else {
    $colorString = $csv_products[$i]['color'];
}
$currentProduct->setColor($colorString);
```

There are ways to avoid building the array of attribute labels and values before the script starts running, but that will require additional lookups and slow the import down.

Comment: Thanks for the response.My attribute is multiple select type.Can you update the code for  multiple select type attribute and one more thing.Can you write the code like this http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/mass-update-stock-levels-in-magento-fast/  so that I can execute it using my browser.

Comment: Updating via the browser is an incredibly bad idea.  It means that a time out will leave you with a half run script.  Although the code is very similar this won't run nearly as quick since it updates and saves the product model, not the product stock model (which is much lighter).

Comment: Also, just added a small bit on how to work with multi-select.  You'll need to piece this code into a full script yourself but its all there.

Comment: Matt thanks a lot now can you Please tell me the steps to execute it.i don't have a dedicated server.

Comment: What are you using for hosting?  You're going to run into serious issues if you aren't running at least a decent VPS with 5,000 products on magento.  I guess you can try to set a long timeout and run it from the browser, worst case you'll end up with only some of your products being updated.  You could also modify this code to push the CSV into a table the first time its run, then delete the row as it saves / updates successfully.